# Why tracemem shows two copies when modification occurs inside function body?

Tags: r, function, copy

Inside a R REPL :

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
> foo <- function (x) x[[1]] <- 0
> a <- 1L:3L
> tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x55d5470e4940>"
> foo(a)
tracemem[0x55d5470e4940 -> 0x55d545e11808]: foo 
tracemem[0x55d545e11808 -> 0x55d5470050c8]: foo
```

I cannot understand why there are two copies and when do they occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Based on joran comment :

The double copy has nothing to do with function call, but it was caused by the conversion of the integer vector into a double vector `b[[1]] <- 0`. Here is the same with no funciton call:

```
> a <- 1L:3L
> tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x556c48022f70>"
> b <- a
> b[[1]] <- 0
tracemem[0x556c48022f70 -> 0x556c46e1e788]: 
tracemem[0x556c46e1e788 -> 0x556c48012118]:
```

And the now with `b[[1]] <- 0L` :

```
> a <- 1L:3L
> tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x556c480f3100>"
> b <- a
> b[[1]] <- 0L
tracemem[0x556c480f3100 -> 0x556c46e1e908]: 
>
```